# Is it possible to use the Geth Console and turn off syncing entirely?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is it possible to use the Geth Console and turn off syncing entirely?

If there is a JS command or another way to make the Geth Console turn off syncing entirely while still being able to use the console commands for testing purposes I would be interested in knowing how to do it.